# Android Studio failed execution

Tags: java, xml, android-studio-2.1

I got the following error when I opened my project in Android Studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library'.
>   Unable to unzip 'C:\Users\Dharmawan's\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\animated-vector-drawable\25.3.1\animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1.aar' to 'C:\Users\Dharmawan's.android\build-cache\13e16c0d483386c8c964b3557f261a501ceb749b\output' or find the cached output 'C:\Users\Dharmawan's.android\build-cache\13e16c0d483386c8c964b3557f261a501ceb749b\output' using the build cache at 'C:\Users\Dharmawan's.android\build-cache'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, executing **Android Studio** as administrator on **Linux**, you won't update the **IDE**.

In this case, I used the `chmod +777` command, to resolve this problem, but the big problem will be the computer vulnerability.

The command is `sudo chmod +777 -R /home/your_user/Android/` or the path where is located the program.

Answer (score 1):

Studio cannot unzip the file due to folder's privileges. To solve it execute Studio with administrator privileges.

In linux terminal (usually in /usr/local/include/android-studio/bin) type:

```
sudo ./studio.sh
```

In windows execute Studio as "Administrator".